# How to keep connection and get correct data from client in Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client, tcplistener

I tried to connect between server and client via Socket.
So, I want to keep this connection of them, and then listening data from client. If data is correct condition, then the server will reply with data input. If data is not correct, continue listening data, which sent from client. I have code as below, but it's wrong.

```cs
private static void server()
{   
    var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.135"), Int32.Parse("8888"));
    // this socket listening connect from client
    var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listener.Listen(10);
    var size = 1024;
    var receiveBuffer = new byte[size];
    while (true)
    {
        // this socket is receive/send data
        var socket = listener.Accept();
        var length = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer);
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
        var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, length);              
        Console.WriteLine($"Received from client: {text}");                    
        if (text.Contains("CLIENT[123]:"))
        {
            Console.Write("#Send to client >>> ");
            var reply = Console.ReadLine();
            var sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply);
            socket.Send(sendBuffer);
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            socket.Close();
            Array.Clear(receiveBuffer, 0, size);
        }
    }
}
```

In client, I will send data like this

```
CLIENT[123]: Hi server, are you ok ?
```

After receive this data from client, because it's right condition, server will respond with content input.
So, I don't know, I mistake something else.
After run server, this data automatically receive from client, although I not send data from client.

[image]

Hence, I expect to keep connection between server and client and only get data from client sent. If data, which sent from client same condition, the server will reply with content.

This is code from the client:

```cs
private static void client()
{
    var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.135"), Int32.Parse("8888"));
    var size = 1024;
    var receiveBuffer = new byte[size];
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("#Send to server >>> ");
        var text = Console.ReadLine();
        var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(serverEndpoint);
        var sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text); 
        socket.Send(sendBuffer);
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        
        //get data from server
        var length = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer);
        var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, length);
        Array.Clear(receiveBuffer, 0, size);
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ["The code is not working" is not very specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work). Can you please [edit] your question to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it?

Comment: Hi @KlausGütter, just add more detail. I think it's interpretable. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you also post your client code?

Comment: @KlausGütter, add client code for example.

Comment: And what was the text you entered at the console (Console.ReadLine)?

Comment: As the first time, i type ```ABC, XYZ``` . The second time, i input ```CLIENT[123]: this is right client```, and so on.

Comment: Do you have some special reason to use sockets specifically? A higher level protocol that takes care of message framing, keep alive messages etc would likely be easier to use and more reliable.

Comment: Hi @JonasH, yes, you are right, i try use hsms protocol (ref link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_SECS_Message_Services) . why do you know ?